# How to Increase Incoming Payload limit above 1 MB in Kubernetes

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, amazon-eks

When I send a post request to my app deployed in EKS, if the request body size is above 1MB, I'm getting the following error from nginx. Help needed on the same to increase the incoming payload size. Thanks in advance.

## 413 Request Entity Too Large

nginx/1.17.8

Comment: does this help: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/413-request-entity-too-large-nginx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This size can be configured by the parameter `client_max_body_size`

You need to add this annotation to your ingress deployment.

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 8m
```

You can check all other annotations here: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/